# How to check web server logs for SQL injection?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server, log-files, sql

If I have a PHP site hosted on Apache and someone hacks it using SQL injection, is there a way I can find out exactly which script caused this by looking at my web server logs?
Or using some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your web server logs are logging the query parameters, then search for known SQL (e.g. `SELECT`) through the logs.

If they're not logging query parameters, then you're unlikely to find anything by searching the logs, rather you'll have to look for patterns - for example a repeated URL that wouldn't normally be repeated.

Comment: Ok this brings me to another question. How do you log query parameters?

Comment: One more thing. Shall I look into access logs or error logs?

Comment: The error logs should show failed hack attempts, not successful ones. So start with the access logs. To see how to change what's getting logged, maybe making a separate log for query parameters only, look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html .

Comment: Can sql statements in query parameters be encoded or are they all recognizable? Is there something other than plain english sql statements that I should be looking for in these logs?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this Linux command string to identify possible SQL injections:

```
egrep -i '\bUNION\b|\bSELECT\b|\bCHAR\b' $access_log
```

You could add in other key terms as well, but those were the ones I was finding in my logs.

To generate a list of offending IP addresses, get a little fancier:

```
egrep -i '\bUNION\b|\bSELECT\b|\bCHAR\b' $access_log | sed -n 's/\([0-9\.]\+\).*/\1/p' | sort | uniq -c
```

Which tallies up the offending IPs by the number of instances:

```
    335 160.153.153.31
   1197 175.138.67.67
    508 76.72.165.79
    208 92.60.66.184
    111 95.143.64.185
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar approach to Ken, but I prefer `awk`.

```
$ access_logs='/var/log/httpd/*access*log*'
$ grep -E -hi '\bUNION\b|\bSELECT\b|\bCHAR\b' $access_logs | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
```

To get a top 10 IP list.  This will also search any old access logs which were gzipped with `logrotate`.

Comment: I highly doubt that for attack vectors like *sql injection* there is much value in figuring out who sent the most requests. A million attempts from bot farms is completely unimportant compared to one success.

Comment: @anx Ok but then downvote the other guy too lol.  And there is _some_ value, not a lot but some.  For developers like me who aren't server guys and need to do _something_ there is value.  Also the million attempts can be important if they slow your server to a crawl.  Who knows, maybe the OP grabs the regex and this and gleans from it to make a fail2ban filter or something.  Either way, I don't see your perfect solution in an answer.

Comment: I understand both point of view about "occurrences and impacts", and this answer does not deserve downvotes considering it's the same as the other one, but with awk, which is fine.